# Inherit namedtuple from a base class in python

Tags: python, inheritance, namedtuple

Is it possible to produce a `namedtuple` which inherits from a base class?

What I want is that `Circle` and `Rectangle` are `namedtuple`s and are inherited from a common base class ('Shape'):

```
from collections import namedtuple

class Shape:
    def addToScene(self, scene):
         ...

Circle=namedtuple('Circle', 'x y radius')
Rectangle=namedtuple('Rectangle', 'x1 y1 x2 y2')
```

How would I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try this:

```
class Circle(Shape, namedtuple('Circle', 'x y radius')):

    pass
```

(You should consider adding [`__slots__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#slots) to all your three classes to save memory and for sightly faster lookups.)

Answer (score 2):

For anyone looking for a way to implement an immutable type that derives from another type, a frozen [`dataclass`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.dataclass) or [`attrs`](https://www.attrs.org/en/stable/) might be a better option than a `namedtuple`.

An example using `dataclass`:

```py
class Base:
    def fun(self):
        print('Base()')


@dataclass(frozen=True)
class MyType(Base):
    x: int
```

This way, you can call `fun()` on a `MyType` instance:

```py
my_type = MyType([1, 2])
my_type.fun()
```

But cannot assign to its members:

```py
my_type = MyType([1, 2])
#my_type.x = [10, 20]
```

Note that mutable members can still be modified:

```py
my_type = MyType([1, 2])
my_type.x[0] = 10
```