# Python: Copying named tuples with same attributes / fields

Tags: python, namedtuple

I am writing a function that takes a named tuple and must return a super set of that tuple.

For example if I was to receive a named tuple like this:

```
Person(name='Bob', age=30, gender='male')
```

I want to return a tuple that looks like this:

```
Person(name='Bob', age=30, gender='male', x=0)
```

Currently I am doing this:

```
tuple_fields = other_tuple[0]._fields
tuple_fields = tuple_fields + ('x')
new_tuple = namedtuple('new_tuple', tuple_fields)
```

Which is fine, but I do not want to have to copy each field like this:

```
tuple = new_tuple(name=other_tuple.name, 
                  age=other_tuple.age, 
                  gender=other_tuple.gender, 
                  x=0)
```

I would like to be able to just iterate through each object in the FIRST object and copy those over. My actual tuple is 30 fields.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inherit namedtuple from a base class in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39098452/inherit-namedtuple-from-a-base-class-in-python)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You could try utilizing dict unpacking to make it shorter, eg:

```
tuple = new_tuple(x=0, **other_tuple._asdict())
```

Comment: Whether namedtuples have a `__dict__` and how it works is rather inconsistent across Python versions. I don't think the latest 3.5 revision has it. Having a `__dict__` for namedtuples was a bad idea in the first place, and it caused some nasty bugs.

Comment: If you want a dict representation of a namedtuple, there's the `_asdict` method.

Comment: @user2357112 Thanks, I'll update my answer for that. `__dict__` worked fine for me, but I'm stuck on Python 3.4.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted version is broken, you will get a `new_tuple() got multiple values for argument 'x'` error.

You should use `_replace` instead:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.somenamedtuple._replace