# Copying all despite of one attributes/fields of one to another namedtuple

Tags: python, python-3.x, namedtuple

What's the shortest way to copy all despite of one attribute/field from one to another namedtuple? It's possible to do it like follows.

```
initial_person = Person(name='Bob', age=30, gender='male')

new_age = 31

modified_person = Person(name=initial_person.name,
                         age=new_age,
                         gender=initial_person.gender,
                  )
```

However I have a lot more fields and would prefer a shorter implementation. This question is related to [Python: Copying named tuples with same attributes / fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40980775/python-copying-named-tuples-with-same-attributes-fields).

Comment: You mean like https://stackoverflow.com/a/22562687/3001761?

Comment: Please clarify what you are asking. Add an example input and output along with some code you have tried. As it sits your question is confusing and I have no clue what you are even asking, nor do I know how to reword it in such a way to make understandable.

Comment: Then yes, you can absolutely use [`_replace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.somenamedtuple._replace): `modified_person = initial_person._replace(age=new_age)`

Comment: @jonrsharpe That's exactly what I was looking for! Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use _replace()

```
initial_person = Person(name='Bob', age=30, gender='male')
modified_person = initial_person._replace(age=31)
```

Note that this is a little hack, theoretically you shouldn't use methods with a underscore at the beginning.

Comment: Like a regular tuple, a `namedtuple` is *immutable*; this gives `AttributeError: can't set attribute`.

Comment: It's not a hack, they're documented methods that are prefixed *"To prevent conflicts with field names"*.