# Inheriting from a namedtuple base class

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, super, namedtuple

This question is asking the opposite of [Inherit namedtuple from a base class in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39098452/inherit-namedtuple-from-a-base-class-in-python) , where the aim is to inherit a subclass from a namedtuple and not vice versa.

In normal inheritance, this works:

```
class Y(object):
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c


class Z(Y):
    def __init__(self, a, b, c, d):
        super(Z, self).__init__(a, b, c)
        self.d = d
```

[out]:

```
>>> Z(1,2,3,4)
<__main__.Z object at 0x10fcad950>
```

But if the baseclass is a `namedtuple`:

```
from collections import namedtuple

X = namedtuple('X', 'a b c')

class Z(X):
    def __init__(self, a, b, c, d):
        super(Z, self).__init__(a, b, c)
        self.d = d
```

[out]:

```
>>> Z(1,2,3,4)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: __new__() takes exactly 4 arguments (5 given)
```

The question, **is it possible to inherit namedtuples as a base class in Python? If so, how?**

Comment: This is not exactly an answer to your question, but it might be worth checking out the new python [dataclasses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html). In most cases where you would override a namedtuple, you might want to use them instead.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can, but you have to override `__new__` which is called implicitly before `__init__`:

```
class Z(X):
  def __new__(cls, a, b, c, d):
    self = super(Z, cls).__new__(cls, a, b, c)
    self.d = d
    return self

>>> z = Z(1, 2, 3, 4)
>>> z
Z(a=1, b=2, c=3)
>>> z.d
4
```

But `d` will be just an independent attribute!

```
>>> list(z)
[1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Can I do `self.append(d)`?

Comment: @alvas No, because `namedtuple` is basically a `tuple` (immutable by design and therefore has no `append`)

Comment: @Mseifert Thanks! But =(

Comment: Is inheriting from `namedtuple` an anti-pattern, or is it a reasonable approach if I just need a coupe extra arguments that I'd like to keep separate from the rest? (Specifically, I want them calculated in `__init__` rather than assigned in user code.)

Comment: I just thought about inheriting a `namedtuple` because I wanted a dataclass with no additional custom methods while supporting iteration over the field values. I don't know if that's an anti-pattern but that would be a real world use case.

Comment: Don't do this; At least the `__repr__` and `__match_args__` will be incorrect, and so will `._fields`, and `._field_defaults` (if your child class has defaults). This could break other code that uses this in very unexpected ways!

Comment: Addiontally, `len` will be incorrect, and methods like `_asdict()` will not work. And worst of all:  the hash  won't include the fields of the child class, which can lead to bugs that are extremely difficult to debug.

Answer (score 16):

I think you can achieve what you want by including all of the fields
in the original named tuple, then adjusting the number of arguments
using `__new__` as schwobaseggl suggests above. For instance, to address
max's case, where some of the input values are to be calculated
rather than supplied directly, the following works:

```
from collections import namedtuple

class A(namedtuple('A', 'a b c computed_value')):
    def __new__(cls, a, b, c):
        computed_value = (a + b + c)
        return super(A, cls).__new__(cls, a, b, c, computed_value)

>>> A(1,2,3)
A(a=1, b=2, c=3, computed_value=6)
```

Answer (score 9):

I came here with the exact same problem, just two years later.
I personally thought that the `@property` decorator would fit in here better:

```
from collections import namedtuple

class Base:
    @property
    def computed_value(self):
        return self.a + self.b + self.c

# inherits from Base
class A(Base, namedtuple('A', 'a b c')):
    pass

cls = A(1, 2, 3)
print(cls.computed_value)
# 6
```

Comment: This is mentioned in documentation now: https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.somenamedtuple._field_defaults

Answer (score 1):

Instead of thinking strictly in terms of inheritance, since `namedtuple` is a function, another approach could be to encapsulate it in a new function.

The question then becomes: "how do we construct a namedtuple that has properties `a, b, c` by default, and optionally some additional ones?"

```
def namedtuple_with_abc(name, props=[]):
     added = props if type(props) == type([]) else props.split()
     return namedtuple(name, ['a', 'b', 'c'] + added)

X = namedtuple_with_abc('X')
Z = namedtuple_with_abc('Z', 'd e')

>>> X(1, 2, 3)
X(a=1, b=2, c=3)

>>> Z(4, 5, 6, 7, 8)
Z(a=4, b=5, c=6, e=7, f=8)
```