# Python3 inheritance from collections.namedtuple: TypeError: object.__init__() takes exactly one argument (the instance to initialize)

Tags: python, inheritance

I want to create a child class of `collections.namedtuple`

This is my code:

```
from collections import namedtuple

TransactionTuple = namedtuple(
    typename="Transactionttt",
    field_names=[
        "transactionDate",
        "valueDate",
        "value",
        "currency",
        "concept"
    ],
    defaults=("",)
)


class TransactionClass(TransactionTuple):
    
    def __init__(self, transactionDate, valueDate, value, currency, concept):
        
        super().__init__(transactionDate, valueDate, value, currency, concept)

print(TransactionClass(1,1,1,1,1))
```

And this is the output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Sync1\Code\Python3\EconoPy\Version_0.2\test.py", line 22, in <module>
    print(TransactionClass(1,1,1,1,1))
  File "D:\Sync1\Code\Python3\EconoPy\Version_0.2\test.py", line 20, in __init__
    super().__init__(transactionDate, valueDate, value, currency, concept)
TypeError: object.__init__() takes exactly one argument (the instance to initialize)
```

I think that the problem is related to `super().__init__()`, but I don't find a solution.

Comment: What is the point of having your own version of `__init__` if it just calls the parent `__init__`?

Comment: @JohnGordon this is a minimal example. I want to implement methods that are irrelevant for the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from collections import namedtuple

TransactionTuple = namedtuple(
    typename="Transactionttt",
    field_names=[
        "transactionDate",
        "valueDate",
        "value",
        "currency",
        "concept"
    ],
    defaults=("",)
)


class TransactionClass(TransactionTuple):

    def __init__(self, transactionDate, valueDate, value, currency, concept):
        super().__init__()

print(TransactionTuple(1, 1, 1, 1, 1))
print(TransactionClass(1, 1, 1, 1, 1))
```

produces

```
Transactionttt(transactionDate=1, valueDate=1, value=1, currency=1, concept=1)
TransactionClass(transactionDate=1, valueDate=1, value=1, currency=1, concept=1)
```

My guess is that the class from `namedtuple` populates its instance through the `__new__` function, and so doesn't actually take anything into its `__init__()` (just a guess).  So if you have other things, you should be able to add them to the `__init__()` you have, or if that's it, then you can just remove it.

Comment: I think your guesses are right, following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42385916/inheriting-from-a-namedtuple-base-class). Although it doesn't makes any reference to the documentation.

Comment: [This](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.10/Lib/collections/__init__.py) is the documentation. I don't have enough knowledge to understand to full code, but I think that the `collections.namedtuple` is populated as the standard `tuple` (I don't know if `tuple` uses `__new__` to be populated).

Comment: [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-zsV0_QrfTw) is useful.